# Node name in elastic search config does not work

Tags: java, configuration, elasticsearch

I tried to set node.name in config of elasticsearch, but i did not see any node that created with my desired name.Here is my elasticsearch.yml file:

```
cluster.name: mycluster
node.name: "mynode"
# Path to directory where to store index data allocated for this node.
path.data: /path/to/data
```

Can you please show me what go wrong here?Thanks you so much.

Comment: what do you mean by "I do not see any node created with the desired name"? Where are you looking?

Comment: Ensure the indentation is correct, check your log file for any errors that may be relevant to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

How it should look - note the space indentation of each uncommented setting.

```
################################### Cluster ###################################

# Cluster name identifies your cluster for auto-discovery. If you're running
# multiple clusters on the same network, make sure you're using unique names.
#
 cluster.name: Test

################################### Cache ####################################
 indices.cache.filter.expire: 5m


#################################### Node #####################################

# Node names are generated dynamically on startup, so you're relieved
# from configuring them manually. You can tie this node to a specific name:
#
 node.name: "Test"
```

Comment: Thank for your reply, but it does not work. i can see ES create cluster and data folder path follow to my config, but only node name is not correct, i do not see ES create node with my name in cluster.